# Node Addon node-gyp build error C2872 'byte': ambiguous symbol

Tags: node-gyp

As part of upgrading a C++ (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010) with nodejs application from node 0.10.26 to node LTS 18.12.1, to compile and build C++ addons, we used node-gyp(node-gyp@9.3.1., Python version 3.11.1. and VS2019 (16.11.32929.386)), when doing node-gyp build, getting below errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\rpcndr.h(192,14): error C2872: 'byte': ambiguous symbol 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\rpcndr.h(191,23): message : could be 'unsigned char byte' 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\cstddef(28,12): message : or       'std::byte' 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\rpcndr.h(962,25): error C2872: 'byte': ambiguous symbol 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\rpcndr.h(191,23): message : could be 'unsigned char byte'
```

Please suggest possible solutions.

[image]

[image]

referred below link and tried suggestions from below link, but nothing worked.

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-C2872:-byte:-ambiguous-symbol/93889?ftype=problem&q=C%3A%5CProgram+Files+%28x86%29%5CWindows+Kits%5C10%5CInclude%5C10.0.19041.0%5Cshared%5Crpcndr.h%28192%2C14%29%3A+error+C2872%3A+%27byte%27%3A+ambiguous+symbol

Answer (score 0):

Where you include `Windows.h`, add the following.

```
#define byte win_byte_override 
#include <Windows.h>
#undef byte
```

This solved it for me.